# Make R Studio plots only show up in new window

Tags: r, rstudio

When using R Studio, I usually just work with an .R file stacked on top of the Console. I keep the other panes (Environment, History, Files, etc) hidden.

But whenever I plot a graph, the other panes automatically pop out of the side bar to show me the Plot pane. Because I work on a laptop, this makes everything too small to see. By clicking the *Zoom* button on the Plots pane, I can get the plot also show up in a new window, but does not prevent the Plots pane from showing up.

*Is there a way to "disable" the Plots pane in R Studio, and force plots show up in a new window?*

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1     jsonlite_1.4     
[3] data.table_1.10.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.2-6
 [3] scales_0.4.1     lazyeval_0.2.0  
 [5] plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.2.3     
 [7] gtable_0.1.2     tibble_1.3.0    
 [9] curl_2.5         Rcpp_0.12.10    
[11] grid_3.2.3       munsell_0.4.2   
>
```

Comment: You can force RStudio to show plots in the Source window if you use R Markdown. In a Rmd file, plots are shown together with code.

Comment: @jsb Interesting. Does this only work when running code from the Rmd file (ie not from the console)? I'll have to try this out; hopefully the graphs are large enough to easily see.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `dev.new()` function will open a new plot window, which then becomes the target for all plots.

If you wish to open another window you can run the command a second time to open a second window.

`dev.off()` will shut down the window (in the order they were opened by default).

You can see how to control multiple graphics devices in the documentation [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/dev.html).

Comment: This was super helpful. In my set up I have RStudio open on a Mac and have a split screen with one half occupied by code and the other by the console (and i've hidden the plot window/environment pane). Both are in 'full screen' mode and i'm taking advantage of Mac OSX's native split screen function. When I use your solution the new Quartz window opens up behind the code + console, but it'd be great if it could load in front so I don't have to switch between desktops to view the graphs

Comment: you're the man, i was looking for this for a while now. i vstudio code i couldn't get the graph to show on a second monitor. this is super helpful. thx a lot.

Comment: How to put the size of the screen to full?

Answer (score 16):

In RStudio, the default graphics device is normally `"RStudioGD"`.  You can change that to something else: the normal choices are `"windows"` on Windows, `"quartz"` on MacOS, `"X11"` on Linux.  So for example, use

```
options(device = "quartz")
```

in your RStudio session on a Mac and you'll get the regular MacOS graphics window.

Comment: This can *not* be properly reset with  `options(device = "RStudioGD")`...

Comment: No, that's not likely to be on the search path.  Best would be to save the old one, and restore it later.  Don't rely on being able to search for it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to restore it now. That helps me understand how this works, thanks.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that the option only stores the name, but for me it restores the device to RStudio's when I use "RStudioGD".  Maybe you kept writing to the current device?  Call `dev.new()` after you change the option, and it will try to open a new one.

Comment: For me if I do that it says   C symbol name "rs_createGD" not in load table." so then I have to set it back to quartz again to have any plotting device. Maybe I'll open a separate question for it.

Comment: @user2554330 I have tried options(device = "windows") but the plot pane keep appearing Rstudio.

Comment: @HermanToothrot:  It still works for me.  Maybe you had the RStudio device open, and it didn't try to open a new device?  Run `dev.off()` until it returns "null device", and try again.

Comment: How to put the size of the screen to full?

Answer (score 10):

Try using the `windows` command before your plot call.

```
windows();(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
```

The plot should pop-up in its own window whilst the pane stays minimized.

Comment: What package is `windows()` in? I get 'Error in windows() : could not find function "windows"'

Comment: Documentation suggests that this is a base function if you are operating on a Windows machine.  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.6.0/topics/windows

Comment: How to put the size of the screen to full?

Answer (score 8):

Commenting the following lines in *C:\Program Files\RStudio\R\Tools.R* seems to work (it may be necessary to edit the file as administrator):

```
# set our graphics device as the default and cause it to be created/set
.rs.addFunction( "initGraphicsDevice", function()
{
   # options(device="RStudioGD")
   # grDevices::deviceIsInteractive("RStudioGD")
  grDevices::deviceIsInteractive()
})
```

Comment: The only simple solution that actually works.

Comment: I guess this file is under */Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/R* on Linux.

Comment: Update 2024: I find the directory at `C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\R`.  This really is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all plots in the current script to appear on a separate window, this should do the job:

```
dev.new(noRStudioGD = TRUE)
```

*Tested on RStudio version 1.4.1106 for Windows with R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)

For a 'permanent' solution, the answer by [Rubén Fernández-Casal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4303451/rub%c3%a9n-fern%c3%a1ndez-casal) should work well.

Answer (score 2):

You can force RStudio to show plots in the Source window if you use R Markdown. In a Rmd file, plots are shown together with code; it's called an R Markdown notebook. You can set the size of the plots too, in what is called an R code chunk:

````
```{r fig.height = 2, fig.width = 3}
plot(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
```
````

When you run the chunk, the plot is shown below it.

If you want to set the plot size for the whole notebook, set the package option using `opts_knit` and `opts_chunk`, for example:

````
```{r setup} 
library(knitr) 
opts_knit$set(global.par = TRUE) 
opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 4.5, fig.height = 3.5)
```
````

For more information, see [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_rcodechunks.html) and [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/options).