# How to stop Rstudio opening plots in new windows

Tags: r, plot, pane

all of a sudden my plots are not showed in the plot-window anymore, but in a separate window, which is quite inconvenient.

I already tried to restart the session, I tried `dev.off()` but that gives me the following

> `error: Error in dev.off():cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)`

I also tried: `while (!is.null(dev.list())) dev.off()` , but this didn't seem to change anything and lastly I tried `graphics.off`, this gave me

```
> function ()
{
while ((which <- dev.cur()) != 1) dev.off(which)
invisible()
}
<bytecode: 0x000002496ce83bb8>
<environment: namespace:grDevices>
```

but once again it still keeps opening a new window.

moreover I checked that I have the newest version of Rstudio, which is the case.

I cannot find what the problem here is, I hope that someone can help me!
Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Does this post help? It's the opposite problem of what you have but still might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534643/make-r-studio-plots-only-show-up-in-new-window

Comment: Does pressing the button with a broomstick in the plot pane fix it?

Comment: I can't press on the broomstick, the plot plane does not show anything and the symbols are kind of blurred.