# Save plots in x11 graphic device in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

In the default RStudio one can right click on the plot to save it. I wanted to open a graphic device in a new window, so following up on the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534643/make-r-studio-plots-only-show-up-in-new-window), I now call,

```
x11()
plot(rnorm(100,0,1))
```

But I can no longer right click on the window to save this plot. How do I do that?

Alternatively I would like to send the plot to a graphic device of specified width and height and have a GUI option to save it just like one has in RstudioGD.

I am on a GNU/Linux distribution using X11.